# How to Strip '$' from Woocommerce Order Total

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I cannot get the dollar sign from Woocommerce Cart Total to strip from value

I have tried all the variations of the code below and added it to my email-order-details.php file. Not a single one of them worked correctly. Either the $totalVal keeps the dollar sign attached to it or $totalVal prints out as a 0.
And when the $totalVal prints as a 0 my if statement still prints. It prints regardless of the if comparator. I'am physically uploading the changes to the webserver and resending the email. I can make it work in test.php file. Well I can get it to not echo the statement but I cannot get it to strip the dollar sign.

```
<div><?php
        $strpTotal = $total['value'];
        $totalVal = floatval(ltrim($strpTotal, "$"));
        if ( $totalVal < 100 ){
                        echo 'My Text';}
                     ?></div>


<div><?php 
        $strpTotal = trim($total['value'], "$");
        if ( $strpTotal < 100 ){
                        echo 'My Text';}
                ?></div>


<div><?php 
        $strpTotal = $total['value'];
        $totalVal = trim($strpTotal, "$");
        if ( $totalVal < 100 ){
                        echo 'My Text';}
                ?></div>
```

Entire File Code Below

```
<?php
/**
 * Order details table shown in emails.
 *
 * This template can be overridden by copying it to yourtheme/woocommerce/emails/email-order-details.php.
 *
 * HOWEVER, on occasion WooCommerce will need to update template files and you
 * (the theme developer) will need to copy the new files to your theme to
 * maintain compatibility. We try to do this as little as possible, but it does
 * happen. When this occurs the version of the template file will be bumped and
 * the readme will list any important changes.
 *
 * @see https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/template-structure/
 * @package WooCommerce/Templates/Emails
 * @version 3.3.1
 */

if ( ! defined( 'ABSPATH' ) ) {
    exit;
}

$text_align = is_rtl() ? 'right' : 'left';

do_action( 'woocommerce_email_before_order_table', $order, $sent_to_admin, $plain_text, $email ); ?>

<h2>
    <?php
    if ( $sent_to_admin ) {
        $before = '<a class="link" href="' . esc_url( $order->get_edit_order_url() ) . '">';
        $after  = '</a>';
    } else {
        $before = '';
        $after  = '';
    }
    /* translators: %s: Order ID. */
    echo wp_kses_post( $before . sprintf( __( '[Order #%s]', 'woocommerce' ) . $after . ' (<time datetime="%s">%s</time>)', $order->get_order_number(), $order->get_date_created()->format( 'c' ), wc_format_datetime( $order->get_date_created() ) ) );
    ?>
</h2>

<div style="margin-bottom: 40px;">
    <table class="td" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="6" style="width: 100%; font-family: 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, Roboto, Arial, sans-serif;" border="1">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th class="td" scope="col" style="text-align:<?php echo esc_attr( $text_align ); ?>;"><?php esc_html_e( 'Product', 'woocommerce' ); ?></th>
                <th class="td" scope="col" style="text-align:<?php echo esc_attr( $text_align ); ?>;"><?php esc_html_e( 'Quantity', 'woocommerce' ); ?></th>
                <th class="td" scope="col" style="text-align:<?php echo esc_attr( $text_align ); ?>;"><?php esc_html_e( 'Price', 'woocommerce' ); ?></th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <?php
            echo wc_get_email_order_items( $order, array( // WPCS: XSS ok.
                'show_sku'      => $sent_to_admin,
                'show_image'    => false,
                'image_size'    => array( 32, 32 ),
                'plain_text'    => $plain_text,
                'sent_to_admin' => $sent_to_admin,
            ) );
            ?>
        </tbody>
        <tfoot>
            <?php
            $totals = $order->get_order_item_totals();

            if ( $totals ) {
                $i = 0;
                foreach ( $totals as $total ) {
                    $i++;
                    ?>
                    <tr>
                        <th class="td" scope="row" colspan="2" style="text-align:<?php echo esc_attr( $text_align ); ?>; <?php echo ( 1 === $i ) ? 'border-top-width: 4px;' : ''; ?>"><?php echo wp_kses_post( $total['label'] ); ?></th>
                        <td class="td" style="text-align:<?php echo esc_attr( $text_align ); ?>; <?php echo ( 1 === $i ) ? 'border-top-width: 4px;' : ''; ?>"><?php echo wp_kses_post( $total['value'] ); ?></td>
                    </tr>
                    <?php
                }
            }
            if ( $order->get_customer_note() ) {
                ?>

                <tr>
                    <th class="td" scope="row" colspan="2" style="text-align:<?php echo esc_attr( $text_align ); ?>;"><?php esc_html_e( 'Note:', 'woocommerce' ); ?></th>
                    <td class="td" style="text-align:<?php echo esc_attr( $text_align ); ?>;"><?php echo wp_kses_post( wptexturize( $order->get_customer_note() ) ); ?></td>
                </tr>
                <?php
            }
            ?>
        </tfoot>
    </table>
    <div><?php
        $strpTotal = $total['value'];
        $totalVal = trim($strpTotal, "$");
        if ( $totalVal < 100 ){
                        echo 'My Text';}
                        echo  $strpTotal;
                        echo  $totalVal;
                ?></div>

</div>

<?php do_action( 'woocommerce_email_after_order_table', $order, $sent_to_admin, $plain_text, $email ); ?>
```

I want to have a conditional PHP if statement in my woocommerce emails. My code should get the cart total and strip the $ off of it. Then compare it and make sure that cart total is less 100 if the total is less then 100 my statement should get printed. Please all help is appreciated.

Comment: `$trpTotal` in the second attempt is missing an **s**...

Comment: I can't duplicate it: https://3v4l.org/YsOsO (with fixed typo)

Comment: that is just a typo here from me typing all three out. I'll fix it now

Comment: @aynber I can get it to not print the statement outside of woocommerce on a test file but once in the email-order-details.php from wocommerce and you send the email it always prints the line and if just echo $totalVal it either sows a 0 or $527.29 never 527.29

Comment: Can you show the code from the actual file?

Comment: @anyber the first example is the code from the file     <div><?php
        $strpTotal = $total['value'];
        $totalVal = floatval(ltrim($strpTotal, "$"));
        if ( $totalVal < 100 ){
                        echo 'My Text';}
                     ?></div>

Comment: @anyber added the entire files code if you wouldn't mind taking a look

Comment: I still can't duplicate it: https://3v4l.org/A15Rt. However, one thing you can try is `preg_replace("/[^0-9.-]/", '', $strpTotal );` and see if that works any better for you.

Comment: @anyber thank you for your help

Comment: @anyber so this actually works and strips the $ but adds '----36' in front of the price.  Any thoughts?

Comment: @anyber thank you it worked I needed to modify the pattern a little but it worked. If you post your comment as an answer I'ld be glad to give you the credit for it.

Answer (score 0):

So thanks to @anyber preg_replace("/[^0-9.-]/", '', $strpTotal ); worked. I had to change [^0-9.-] to $ which represents the dollar sign in html. Before any says anything I did try using this with trim ltrim and floatval sequences above before ever coming here. I did try pre_replace once but didn't understand the /[^0-9,-]/ part and my initial attempt using it didn't work so I tried using the commands I understood better. If @anyber would like to post there answer as the answer I would be glad to give them the credit.